# View() ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Csharp_ASPNetCore.Pages.Shared
{

    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {

        public ExampleController()
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/example/")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/example/")]
        public IActionResult Index(string someValue)
        {
            string buttonClicked = "";


            if (HttpContext.Request.Form.ContainsKey("btnOne"))
            {
                buttonClicked = "btnOne";
                int a = 1;
                int b = 2;
                int c = a + b;
                // return View("AAAAAA");

            }
            else if (HttpContext.Request.Form.ContainsKey("btnTwo"))
            {
                buttonClicked = "btnTwo";
            }

            return View("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

The last `View("Index")` command doesn't work, returning this error:

> "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Example/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cs

Following I report the `Index.cshtml` where there are the buttons (the name of the controller is ExampleController.cs). Thanks!

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div>
    <form asp-controller="example" asp-action="Index">
        <label>Value:</label>
        <input name="someValue" type="text" maxlength="10"/>
        <button name="btnOne" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Click One</button>
        <button name="btnTwo" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Click Two</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a very clear error message. Do you have an `Index.cshtml` in either of those locations?

Comment: *Where* does that `Index.cshtml` file live? It looks like it's a Razor Page, so it looks like you're mixing Razor Pages and standard MVC here.

Comment: If that listed file *is* a view for your controller, then it should not have the `@page` directive.

Comment: Kirk Larkin you are right...I'm focusing now on Razor Page